# masked asserts in C++

Tags: c++, assert

I've been adding a module to http://minisat.se/MiniSat.html package. I had a bunch of `asserts` that I now realize are neither getting triggered nor even compiled. How it can be? I searched the net for "masked asserts", but no clue. Can it be that the make rules for the package somehow remove the assertions? Even `assert(0)` was not causing the program to SIGABORT...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check your preprocessor settings. When `NDEBUG` (i.e. `-DNDEBUG` on the compiler commandline) is defined, all asserts will be removed.

Answer (score 3):

The assert macro depends on the definition NDEBUG.

If NDEBUG is defined then assert is defined as:

```
#define assert(ignore) ((void)0)
```

assert only does checking in debug mode, but not in release mode.

Comment: hm, so "ignore" is some keyword as well? Thanks guys, I removed "-D NDEBUG" line in the makefile template, and now it works.

Comment: No. `ignore` is not a keyword. It is the macro parameter, which is ignored by the macro definition in this case.